# Cisco port down and notconnect after changing port speed

Tags: cisco

In my network, I have a main Cisco 2950 that connects to my outside bandwidth, then individual Cisco 2950s in each cabinet that connect back to the main one.

I recently had someone in one cabinet start consuming 100% of the bandwidth in my network.  As a quick fix, I set the speed on the main switch to be 10Mbps for the port that connects to the switch in the cabinet.

After doing that however, the port now shows down (notconnect).  I've tried setting the speed back to 100, and shutting down/starting the port again, but it never reconnects.  Any recommendations on getting this port back up, short of rebooting the switch in the end cabinet (I can't connect to the switch)

Here is what I did:

```
config t
int FastEthernet1/0/47
speed 100
duplex full
end
```

Even after resetting the speed, I'm getting:

```
sh int FastEthernet1/0/47
FastEthernet1/0/47 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) 
  Hardware is Fast Ethernet, address is 0016.4797.4633 (bia 0016.4797.4633)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000 Kbit, DLY 1000 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 73/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, media type is 10/100BaseTX
```

Before changing the speed:

```
sh int FastEthernet1/0/47
FastEthernet1/0/47 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
  Hardware is Fast Ethernet, address is 0016.4797.4633 (bia 0016.4797.4633)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 209/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, media type is 10/100BaseTX
```

Comment: Try setting the port to auto-negotiate.  And, well, you do now know why what you did isn't a good idea to deal with a bandwidth hog, right?

Comment: I've tried "speed auto", but it not work.  What eventually did was "duplex auto".  The "speed 10" works pretty well when a server is connected directly to the switch, but switch-to-switch, obviously not.  Thanks

Comment: 1. So the user is consuming 100% of all the bandwidth of all the links/ports? Wow, that is pretty amazing. 2. How is setting the port to 10Mbps going to help? If they're consuming 100% of a 100Mbps or 1Gbps link then certainly they're going to consume 100% of a 10Mbps link. My advice: find a different solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the comments, the solution was set the port to autonegotiate, rather than manually defining speed and duplex settings.

And this kind of problem (as well as other potential issues) is why it's a bad idea to limit bandwidth by forcing a switch-to-switch port to a lower speed and/or duplex setting manually.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue in my home lab and found the cause.

That fact that is show down down(not connect) mean a physical issue. It seems weird, since the port was working good before changing the speed.

If that switch port is connect to another switch, it would need a crossover cable but if you have Straight-Through it wont work unless the auto-mdix feature kicks in, BUT the auto-MDIX feature work only when the speed and duplex are set to auto.

Basically, if you are using the wrong cable type and rely on auto-mdix to get connectivity, you must keep the speed and duplex to auto. Otherwise, change the cable type.

You can use the following command to see the operating state of auto-mdix.

SW1#**show controllers ethernet-controller fastEthernet 1/0/1 phy** .

Note, the automatic medium-dependent interface crossover (Auto-MDIX) feature is enabled by default on switches running Cisco IOS Release 12.2(18)SE or later. When the Auto-MDIX feature is enabled, the switch detects the required cable type for copper Ethernet connections and configures the interfaces accordingly. Therefore, you can use either a crossover or a straight-through cable for connections to a copper 10/100, 10/100/1000, or 1000BASE-T SFP module port on the switch, regardless of the type of device on the other end of the connection.

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault. Please take care more to the spelling (sentences start with capital case, end with a point, and so on). It is a site for professional knowledge exchange, not a chat. Look, how better is your answer now. It already deserves an upvote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, this is not the best way to take care of this problem.  However, for some specifics as to why things worked the way they did for you, it's worth knowing that the main problem came from having one side set manually, and the other side set statically.

As soon as you manually set the duplex on one side, you needed to also set the duplex on the other side as well.  Auto-negotiation wouldn't work in this case if one side has a manually set duplex.  This is why setting it back to auto-negotiate fixed the problem (although not the bandwidth hog problem).

In addition, messing with the duplex on only one switch could have caused the port to go into err-disable state requiring manual console into the other switch and resetting the port.